# How to display the parameter received in ts file to html page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am new to ionic framework. Here I am trying to display the parameter received from home page in my new page. I have tried following codes. But nothing is displayed at the moment. Can anybody tell me what I am missing.

Thank you.

about.ts

```
export class AboutPage {
    userProfile: any = null;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.userProfile = navParams.get("userProfile");
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad AboutPage');
    }
    goBack() {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }
}
```

about.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <p>This is About Us Page.</p>
    <ion-card *ngIf="userProfile">
        <img [src]="userProfile.photoURL"/>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                {{ userProfile.displayName }}
            </ion-card-title>
            <p>
                The UID for this new user is {{userProfile.uid}} and the email is {{userProfile.email}}
            </p>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: what does the code for `navParams` look like?  are you sure it is returning the object you expect?

Comment: @Claies yes i am getting value something like this "{"uid":"121221","displayName":"Test User","photoURL":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s100x100/13891932_1288454467839950_3149500025504162596_n.jpg?

Comment: I understand my mistake. I have to do JSON.parse to this data

Comment: Try subscription method, in case you need to update userprofile.

Comment: @Charles Zha what is subscription method?

Answer (score 2):

Check this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

It's not necessary to use subscription to update userProfile. This might be helpful when some event (like, login(), loadProfile()) is triggered. Because this will trigger the corresponding task which you can include the function `this.userProfile = navParams.get("userProfile");` or other related ones.